# How many times did the Kohanim carry the Aron?

Tags: mitzvah, kohen-priest, ark-aron-kodesh

We know that it is a mitzvah for the Kohanim to transport the Aron. Do we know how many times this mitzvah was performed?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think we would know that? I find the possibility vanishingly unlikely

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the Leviim? 42 times in the midbar? (Actually, the first few times there was no aron yet.)

Comment: @Michoel what about when they went to war? Or when Moshe took the Aron out of the camp to protest? Or if they went on multiday trips?

Comment: Some of those might depend on issues of more than one aron, which one went to war etc.? As for multi-day trips, I always wondered about that. Do we know if that list of places does or does not include every nightly stop on a multi-day trip? Is that what Bamidbar 9:21 means?